# How to turn an Oracle multi-parameter subquery into an MS SQL subquery(ies)

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We're converting some old Oracle stuff to MS SQL Server and Oracle has multi-parameter subqueries and I'm trying to figure out how to do this in MS SQL Server. I'm not very familiar with the Oracle syntax and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to convert it.

The relevant part of the original where clause is:

```
and (rate.tax_code, rate.effect_date) in 
        (select tax_code, max(effect_date)
         from   v_txtaxrate
         where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
         group by tax_code)
```

I tried making it two subqueries as:

```
and rate.tax_code in 
    (select tax_code
         from   v_txtaxrate
         where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
         group by tax_code)
and rate.effect_date in 
    (select max(effect_date)
         from   v_txtaxrate
         where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
         group by tax_code);
```

but the results show these to not be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use "EXISTS" instead of "IN":

```
and exists (
  select 1 
  from (select tax_code, max(effect_date) effect_date
         from   v_txtaxrate
         where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
         group by tax_code) a
  where rate.tax_code = a.tax_code
    and rate.effect_date = a.effect_date
)
```

Comment: Going with yours because you were the first to answer and it works AND it makes sense to me. Now I actually understand what the query is doing. Thanks to all of you guys for answering!

Answer (score 3):

The oracle code requires the [rate].[tax_code] rows to have a [effect_date] the same as the most recent one in the view.

**Correct?**

```
-- ORACLE SNIPPET
and (rate.tax_code, rate.effect_date) in 
       (select tax_code, max(effect_date)
         from v_txtaxrate
         where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
         group by tax_code)
```

Therefore, a inner join to a derived table simply solve this issue.  The derived table grabs the most recent date per each tax code.

```
-- TSQL SNIPPET
select 
  *
from 
  rate inner join 
  (
    select tax_code, max(effect_date) as max_effect_date
    from  v_txtaxrate
    where  effect_date <= '20140110'
    group by tax_code
  )  d_tax
on
  rate.tax_code = d_tax.tax_code and
  rate.effect_date = d_tax.max_effect_date
```

Since I do not have your schema to test, I am inner joining the [rate] table to a derived [d_tax] tax table on code and effective date.  Any records that do not match in this join are dropped out.

See my blog article on derived tables.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1144

Also, use a date literal that is universal.  'YYYYMMDD' is such a format.  See matrix on MSDN showing which formats have the most uses.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution and extra details. Gave you an up vote for it, but gave the check to the first answer, which also worked. I just stuck the date in there for testing. It's actually a parameter in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
and exists
(
    select tax_code, effect_date
    from
    (
        select tax_code, max(effect_date) as effect_date
        from   v_txtaxrate
        where  effect_date <= '10-JAN-14'
        group by tax_code
    ) t
    where tax_code = rate.tax_code
    and effect_date =  rate.effect_date
)
```